# Swift StatusBarの色をイベントから変更したい

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

下記のようなコードでステータスバーの色を変更できるのはわかりました。

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
```

しかし、たとえばUIButtonを押した時に色を変更させたい場合はどのように書けば良いのでしょうか？

アニメーションと共に変更できるようにしたいです。

Answer (score 1):

こちらのメソッドを実行することでstyleを反映させることが可能です。

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621354-setneedsstatusbarappearanceupdat

> Indicates to the system that the view controller status bar attributes have changed.
>
> Call this method if the view controller's status bar attributes, such as hidden/unhidden status or style, change. If you call this method within an animation block, the changes are animated along with the rest of the animation block.